# Was the Indian animated movie Swami Ayyappan ever released?

Tags: distribution, swami-ayyappan

In 2012, the Indian animation studio Toonz Animation announced it was making an animated movie called [Swamy Ayyappan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Ayyappan_(2012_film)) about the Hindu god Ayyappa. You can see the trailer for it here:

But my question is, **was this movie ever released in any form, whether in theaters, direct-to-DVD, or online?**

Wikipedia and IMDB say the release date was October 29, 2012, but I think that's out-of-date information.  [This post](https://www.facebook.com/SwamiAyyappanMovie/posts/573395122762009) from the official Facebook page says it was still in post-production as of November 2014.  So did it release some time between November 2014 and now?  If not, is it going to release in future?

Comment: Some movies get stuck for distribution issues.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, that's a possibility, because the November 2014 Facebook post says "Swami Ayyappan is in the post- production phase and we're hoping for distributors."

Answer (score 1):

Actually this movie is released and avaliable on amazon prime video. And movie premier also happened on big magic channel where i watch the movie in hindi. Lots of people don't know because they are not aware of that.

Comment: Hello welcome to [Movies.SE].  Can you give a screenshot of this movie being available on Amazon Prime or somewhere else? Just for the sake of reference.

Answer (score -1):

Well some movies get stuck because of distribution issues.

> But my question is, was this movie ever released in any form, whether in theaters, direct-to-DVD, or online?

It seems that this is being sold on **[Amazon.in](http://www.amazon.in/SWAMY-AYYAPPAN-ANIMATION-MOVIE-TAMIL/dp/B01N5FPOV3)**. At the time of writing this answer `(11 May 2017)` it's out of stock.

Comment: I think Amazon just listed it because they were planning to release it on DVD.  But I still haven't seen any indication that they actually did.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yes it appears that it never landed in market. There are no reviews or any indication. Well good luck with hunting. **☺☻**

Comment: I hope it was released, because I really want to see it.

Comment: Downvoter please take time to explain how it was not helpful to question by OP ?

Comment: [Rahul](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/41237/rahul): Not a answer. You're just guessing. (I'm rolling back the downvote)

Comment: Somedays ago I'm sure I had found the movie page with Hindi dub, on hotstar, but can't find it now :( it seems to be replaced with live action 1991 kannada movie dubbed into Malayalam.